# How to trigger all checks in a PR that was open by @github-actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action that opens a PR to cherry-pick commits from one branch to another. That's already working. The problem is that GitHub has a policy that prevents PRs opened by the @github-actions bot from running checks automatically.

The only way I found of running the checks for the cherry-pick PR is closing the PR and reopening it. But its quite weird having a message of closing/reopening in the PR logs.
So, I tried to create an action to start the checks with a comment in the PR. But I don't know how to trigger the checks.

My last attempt is in this file https://github.com/hbelmiro/pr-backporting-test/blob/b49f9f1d9adc1755fca9b0da638d07a52eb6436f/.github/workflows/checks.yml.
It fails with "message": "Resource not accessible by integration".

Here I have one of the PRs opened by the cherry-pick action: https://github.com/hbelmiro/pr-backporting-test/pull/14

Does anyone know a way to start the checks with a comment or any other way?